# Get row with the minimum date from a joined table but don't show this date?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Here is part of my query:

```
SELECT
    my1.data AS PAW_ID,
    abc.abc_medium AS abc_Medium,
    my.data AS Trial_Date,
    my2.data AS Upgrade_Date,
    my3.lastmod AS Cancel_Date
```

There are several joins in between. The result set gives multiple instances of `PAW_ID` when I would only like one. I know that when the query is joined to another table, `abc_emails.def208`, then the records where the earliest `def208.created` row exists are the rows that I need.

So if the query above produced the following duplicate data:

```
123 | email | 1-1-2014 | 2-1-2014 | 3-1-2014
123 | banner| 4-1-2014 | 2-1-2014 | 3-1-2014
```

I know that this `PAW_ID` (123) corresponds to data in `abc_emails.def208` where the `MIN(def208.created)` should return the row with email in it.

`def208.created` is not in the `SELECT` part of the query, but I do want to draw upon it. How do I select this value and group by everything else, but keep it hidden? The only thing it is needed for is to get the earliest associated data points to each `PAW_ID`.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your query or table structure?

Comment: Do you mean `WHERE <one of your dates> = (SELECT MIN(created) FROM def208)`?

Comment: Note that dates in SQL adhere to a specific format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish this using a subquery. You can create a table that has the PAW_ID and the minimum date, and join that with your other tables where the PAW_ID and date matches, that way it would eliminate the rows you don't want. Without knowing your table structure it would be hard to give the exact query but I imagine you could do something like this:

```
SELECT columnsIWant
FROM tables
JOIN otherTables ON conditions
JOIN (SELECT paw_id, MIN(created) AS minDate
      FROM def208
      GROUP BY paw_id) tempTable
   ON tempTable.paw_id = realTable.paw_id AND tempTable.minDate = realTable.created;
```

As long as you don't have `SELECT tempTable.minDate` it shouldn't show up in your result set.

**EDIT**

Another way instead of using another JOIN is to try putting it in your where clause like this:

```
SELECT columnsIWant
FROM tables 
JOIN otherTables ON conditions
WHERE realDef208.created = (SELECT MIN(created) FROM tempDef208 WHERE tempDef208.paw_id = realDef208.paw_id);
```

Comment: I had to cancel the query before leaving for the day. Our sr developer gets upset if I leave queries running on our server due to an incident which happened in the past. I'm going to start running it again on Monday am. Sorry to leave you hanging, I appreciate the answer and will update once it eventually gets to run.

Comment: @DougFirr must be a large dataset. Well, I hope it works out for you.

Comment: @DougFirr just checking back in because I was really curious on this one. If you haven't run it yet, just ignore this. Or if it didn't work, let me know and I can look into it again.

Comment: It's running! I'm hoping it fullfills. Seems our server has a hard time with subqueries.

Comment: @DougFirr if you don't have any luck I gave another option that came to mind, but I'm not sure if it would work any better than the first. I can't guarantee it won't be worse, either. I'm not an expert in efficiency.

Comment: I got the query to run. There's a lot of duplicates (results set is about 4.5 times bigger than expected). I'm just trying to ascertain which part of the query is doing this then will repost here. What was the alternative, out of curiosity?

Comment: I eventually re-posted the question in a different format. I hope I've made it easier to see my issue. Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer nonetheless: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236004/sql-get-only-data-associated-with-a-minimum-date-elsewhere-in-database

Answer (score 1):

Create a View which selects Distinct(paw_id) & Min(created) from your current data and join the view with your normal table(s) on both the id & date, this will isolate the row you are looking for without having to select the unwanted date.